# What are these sentences meaning to use Rasa NLU?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I'm making a Chatbot for foreign students to recommend restaurant or facilities for my project assignments
So I bought a book and followed a tutorial.
I can't find a requirments.txt or requirements_full.txt.
Is it necessary to make the project?

```
git clone https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu.git
cd rasa_nlu
pip install -r alt_requirements/requirements_full.txt

ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'alt_requirements/requirements_full.txt'
```